# Different number of available images between Scenes Explorer, Planet Explorer, and API

Tags: planet

I'm attempting to download all PlanetScope 3 Band imagery that overlays ontop of an area of interest defined by a geojson file. The geojson file I'm using is seen here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/621a279e1d6a56aa19844e9c99eb1e1d

When I go to the Scene Explorer and upload my geojson file as the area of interest, then adjust the timeline to "All Time", it says there are 36 scenes avialable.

When I go to the Planet Explorer and upload my geojson file as the area of interest, then adjust the timeline to "All Time", and set the type to types to "3 Band PlanetScope scene", it says there are 47 scenes available.

I have also used the API to conduct the same search. I created an API search filter using the geometry from the geojson file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f1943d3a1e9dbe5d4f7c2aaf631bcb1f . I conducted the search by using the 'download.py' script availbe through the Planet Docs. The code I used to conduct the search was:

```
download.py --query geom_filter.json --search PSScene3Band visual
```

Running this displayed that there was 64 available images.

So my questions are, why am I seeing different numbers for each search method?

And which method is delivering the accurate number of images?

Am I using any of the search methods incorrectly?

(Note: Searches were done on 2/1/2017)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scenes Explorer uses Planet's older v0 API, whereas Planet Explorer is built on top of the Data API. The two APIs expose data differently and you will get the same or more 3-band scenes with the Data API.

In Planet Explorer, the number results are grouped by days, so `47` is actually the number of days that have imagery rather than the total number of images.

One other tangential note, the ellipsis at the bottom of the right-hand panel opens up a code snippet that reveals how the current search is being conducted in Planet Explorer.
[image: Ellipsis]

You can copy and paste this cURL command to see the results on the terminal.

[image: cURL request]

Disclaimer: I work at Planet.

Comment: This answer helped a lot.  I checked the Planet Explorer and for the 47 days of imagery, there are a total of 64 image availalbe (multiple images on some days). This matches the number of available images returned from my API seach, which also uses the newer Data API. I checked the image IDs shown in the Explorer to the IDs from the API search, and they match. Thanks for the help!